# Illumination mask for a mesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

I have a scene with no lighting what so ever.

the white in the image is a procedurally generated 2d mesh that i would like to use as a light source

what i am trying to do is apply a texture or mask that will illuminate the boxes in the background when you look through the mesh. the objects that are being collided with i can simply swap out the textures for a self illuminating texture but i am unsure as were or how to proceed to get the background illuminated.

Comment: If you need help you would need to be more specific for what purpose should that "mask" serve. Should it be realtime mesh light? if so you are out of luck cause Unity does not support realtime lights of custom geometry. What you can do is to use this mask in post process effect with normal map to capture light that should be transferred to object surfaces and define falloff for that. I would start my search in Image Effects package. Look how glow is implemented and continue from there. If you want this planes to be lights for bakin

Comment: thanks heaps,i was fairly confident that it was not possible with unity textures ect however you have pointed me in the right direction